# Servlet 3.0 async Supported disadvantages

Tags: java, asynchronous, servlet-3.0

In my application I have a homegrown framework which maps all the requests to a central ControllerServlet (nothing fancy, it has the basic functionality of almost any framework).
I have to implement a Publisher-Subscriber messaging exchange feature and I decided to use Servlet 3.0's asynchronous methods.

The current `ControllerServlet` and `AuthenticationFilter` are not setted as asyncSupported. I could either implement a second CotrollerServlet for all the async processing or declare the existing ControllerServlet as `asyncSupported=true` (even though there are requests that do not need async processing ).

*... for an application to use the asynchronous feature, the entire request processing chain must have the have this attribute set either through the annotation or in its deployment descriptor ...*
[- source](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3)

From here I understand that I have to declare the `AuthenticationFilter` as `asyncSupported=true` (and again there are cases when the async is not needed).

Is there any downsides of declaring servlets and filters as `asyncSupported=true` even though they also map requests that do not need async processing? Will there be any scalability problems?

Answer (score 1):

The *2.3.3.3 Asynchronous processing* chapter of [Java Servlet 3.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) contains a hint:

> Dispatching from a synchronous servlet to an asynchronous servlet would be illegal.
>   However the decision of throwing an IllegalStateException is differed to the
>   point when the application calls startAsync. **This would allow a servlet to either
>   function as a synchronous or an asynchronous servlet.**

It's not stated directly, but this sentence makes me believe that such dual synchronous/asynchronous nature of one servlet isn't something unusal as far as JLS authors are concerned.

On the other hand consult your container's documentation/source code. Just because it's legal from JLS point of view doesn't mean your container isn't doing some clever optimizations that have negative impact on performance if `AsyncContext` isn't really used. Otherwise, if all servlets could simply work in either mode, what would be the purpose of this attribute, except documenting?

Comment: Hi Tomasz! Yes you are right about that but I'm concerned that there might be some sort of performance affected when declaring the servlet as async. If not, I don't see why not make the `asyncSupported=true` the default value

Comment: Exactly:)) I couldn't find anything about downsides of any kind in this matter.